# Issue with getting NA only response from my Random Forest Model

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, linear-regression, random-forest

this is my first post on Stake overflow so please ask me follow questions if more info is needed!

Situation: I've complied water chemistry data for the Maritimes (Atlantic Canada) for freshwater ecosystems because I am trying to create a predictive species distribution model using a random forest model (RFM) for an invasive species. Unfortunately, Atlantic Canada lack consistent water monitoring programs and the ones that do exist don't monitor for the same parameters as other group. So, my databases (both the training and testing) have many NAs.

Issue: This is the response I keep getting from my RFM:

```
> p1 <- predict(model2, newdata=Test_Dataset,type="prob")[,2]
> p1
```

1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
35 36 37 
NA NA NA

What I have tried:

1. I built the RFM (i.e. model2) using various predictors. I did include:

   model2 <- randomForest(CMS ~ Lat + Lon + pH + Alkalinity + Ca + Hardness + DO + TOC + T_P + T_N + Cond + Na + No_Stocking + No_Fish_Species + Dist_Hwy + No_Boat_Launches + Connected_Lakes + Invasives, importance = TRUE, data=TrainSet, na.action=na.roughfix)
   model2

**Note that the big list of variables are the predictors and CMS is the species.

2. I tried matching the test dataset (Test_Dataset) with the training dataset (Validation_Dataset).

   Test_Dataset <- rbind(Validation_Dataset[1, ] , Validation_Dataset)
   Test_Dataset <- Test_Dataset[-1,]
3. I have searched for and read multiple resources (including the obvious R pages and references linked there).
4. I have mutated the dataframe as follows (I'll just show the Validation_Dataset as it is the same mutations for both):

   ## Mutate dataset to fix issues with R reading NA cells

   Validation_Dataset <- Validation_Dataset %>%
     dplyr::mutate(
       # convert year into a categorical variable
       Year = factor (Year),
       #convert Chlorophyll concentrations from a character file to a number file
       # convert "NA" into a missing value data whenever appropriate
       Chlorophyll = dplyr::na_if(Chlorophyll, "NA"),
       Chlorophyll = factor (Chlorophyll),
       Hardness = dplyr ::na_if(Hardness, "NA"),
       Hardness= factor (Hardness),
       Alkalinity = dplyr::na_if(Alkalinity, "NA"),
       Alkalinity = factor (Alkalinity),
       Ca = dplyr::na_if(Ca, "NA"),
       Ca = factor (Ca),
       TOC = dplyr::na_if(TOC, "NA"),
       TOC = factor (TOC),
       Cond = dplyr::na_if(Cond, "NA"),
       Cond = factor (Cond),
       Na = dplyr::na_if(Na, "NA"),
       Na = factor (Cond),
       NH4 = dplyr::na_if(NH4, "NA"),
       NH4 = factor (NH4),
       NO3 = dplyr::na_if(NO3, "NA"),
       NO3 = factor (NO3),
       pH = dplyr::na_if(pH, "NA"),
       pH = factor (pH),
       T_N = dplyr::na_if(T_N, "NA"),
       T_N = factor (T_N),
       T_P = dplyr::na_if(T_P, "NA"),
       T_P = factor (T_P),
       DO = dplyr::na_if(DO, "NA"),
       DO = factor (DO),
       Salinity = dplyr::na_if(Salinity, "NA"),
       Salinity = factor (Salinity),
       No_Stocking = dplyr::na_if(No_Stocking, "NA"),
       No_Stocking = factor (No_Stocking),
       No_Fish_Species = dplyr::na_if(No_Fish_Species, "NA"),
       No_Fish_Species = factor (No_Fish_Species),
       Dist_Hwy = dplyr::na_if(Dist_Hwy, "NA"),
       Dist_Hwy = factor (Dist_Hwy),
       No_Boat_Launches = dplyr::na_if(No_Boat_Launches, "NA"),
       No_Boat_Launches = factor (No_Boat_Launches),
       Connected_Lakes = dplyr::na_if(Connected_Lakes, "NA"),
       Connected_Lakes = factor (Connected_Lakes),
       Invasives = dplyr::na_if(Invasives, "NA"),
       Invasives = factor (Invasives),
       Lat = factor (Lat),
       Lon = factor (Lon),
       CMS = factor (CMS))

Question: Does anybody know how to actually make the coding work so that model2 predicts on Test_Dataset? I think this problem might actually be very small, but I'm not seeing it.

Here is a glimpse of the training dataset (Validation_Dataset):

```
> str(Validation_Dataset)
Classes ‘spec_tbl_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    37 obs. of  31 variables:
 $ Name            : chr  "Canard River" "Cedar Creek" "Holland River" "Speed River" ...
 $ STN #/COUNTY    : chr  "10000200202" "16001800202" "3007700202" "16018403402" ...
 $ Province        : chr  "ON" "ON" "ON" "ON" ...
 $ Lat             : Factor w/ 37 levels "42.03204214",..: 2 1 11 9 10 8 7 5 6 3 ...
 $ Lon             : Factor w/ 37 levels "-83.01879548",..: 1 2 11 8 10 6 7 9 5 4 ...
 $ Year            : Factor w/ 9 levels "2007, 2011","2010, 2015, 2011",..: 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
 $ Month           : chr  "4" "4" "4" "4" ...
 $ Day             : chr  "11" "12" "26" "27" ...
 $ Data Source     : chr  "ON Provincial (Streams) Water Quality Monitoring Network" "ON Provincial (Streams) Water Quality Monitoring Network" "ON Provincial (Streams) Water Quality Monitoring Network" "ON Provincial (Streams) Water Quality Monitoring Network" ...
 $ pH              : Factor w/ 35 levels "6.073333","6.13",..: 18 21 28 29 25 34 30 32 19 26 ...
 $ Alkalinity      : Factor w/ 31 levels "1.8","2.8","3.933333333",..: 19 22 31 30 27 NA NA 26 NA 21 ...
 $ Hardness        : Factor w/ 13 levels "14.8","36.8",..: 7 8 11 10 9 NA NA 13 NA NA ...
 $ Ca              : Factor w/ 24 levels "3.833333333",..: 18 19 24 20 21 NA NA 22 NA NA ...
 $ Chlorophyll     : Factor w/ 15 levels "0.423601","0.453791",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ DO              : Factor w/ 26 levels "0.27","6.2","6.96",..: 21 24 18 16 4 25 17 14 2 7 ...
 $ TOC             : Factor w/ 3 levels "4.8","5.5","8.8": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ T_P             : Factor w/ 24 levels "0.002","0.003",..: 23 22 18 10 15 14 16 13 21 20 ...
 $ T_N             : Factor w/ 32 levels "0.006","0.13",..: 30 31 27 28 17 29 24 32 21 25 ...
 $ NO3+NO2         : num  2.173 2.292 1.092 1.695 0.426 ...
 $ NO3             : Factor w/ 32 levels "0.027","0.035",..: 30 31 26 27 11 29 24 32 22 8 ...
 $ NH4             : Factor w/ 27 levels "0.005","0.006",..: 26 25 22 17 9 11 13 19 23 27 ...
 $ Cond            : Factor w/ 34 levels "41","97","134",..: 24 21 29 23 22 14 34 31 21 17 ...
 $ Salinity        : Factor w/ 9 levels "0.11","0.15",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Na              : Factor w/ 34 levels "41","97","134",..: 24 21 29 23 22 14 34 31 21 17 ...
 $ No_Stocking     : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 1 2 2 3 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ No_Fish_Species : Factor w/ 9 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 4 6 4 1 5 1 9 1 9 ...
 $ Dist_Hwy        : Factor w/ 16 levels "0.003","0.006",..: NA NA 16 NA NA NA NA 8 NA 5 ...
 $ No_Boat_Launches: Factor w/ 8 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 1 1 5 1 1 1 1 8 1 3 ...
 $ Connected_Lakes : Factor w/ 11 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 7 2 3 4 9 6 2 3 2 5 ...
 $ Invasives       : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ CMS             : Factor w/ 2 levels "NO","YES": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

Comment: In the documents, if na.roughfix is for numeric variables, NAs are replaced with column medians. Was your median that na value?

Comment: To make good answer, give more information.

Comment: Sang won kim, I've edited the post. I hope this additional information helps. I have mutated the dataset to list each variable as "factor" rather than "as.numeric" because I read somewhere that RFM struggle with numeric variables.

Answer (score 0):

To use the argument na.roughfix. It must first be specified outside the randomForest function if it were to be used. I will use the iris dataset as an example.

```
iris.roughfix <- na.roughfix(iris.na)
iris.narf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., iris.na, na.action=na.roughfix)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I change most of my variables to "as.numeric" in the mutation code provided above (Note: I did leave CMS, Lat, and Lon as factors).

Comment: > Validation_Dataset.roughfix <- na.roughfix(TrainSet)
Error in na.roughfix.data.frame(TrainSet) : 
  na.roughfix only works for numeric or factor

Comment: I also tried: > Validation_Dataset.roughfix <- na.roughfix(Validation_Dataset)
Error in na.roughfix.data.frame(Validation_Dataset) : 
  na.roughfix only works for numeric or factor